# How to convert binary installer into rpm?

Tags: software-installation, rpm, intellij

There are times when all you have is binary installer. I hate them because once installed it is quite difficult to uninstall such software, and since my distro (openSUSE 11.4) is rpm-based it is hard to get consistent info about what is installed in the system.

Is there any way to convert binary installer into rpm? **For my own purposes only!** (it means the machine -- e.g. CPU -- is exactly the same).

The only idea I have -- it is a crazy one -- is to create virtual system (with VBox for example) list all files in the system, execute installer, list all files again. Check what was added, copy those files, and in rpm spec add those files with simple "cp" command.

It is tiresome, but it is worse than that because installer can alter some files, so they would be listed in both cases. So I am looking for something smarter.

For now I would like to make rpm for IntelliJ IDEA.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Use [rpmbuild](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm-snapshot/rpmbuild.8.html) to build rpm package.

Here is a nice [tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-rpm1/).

In short, you will have to:

1. unpack the content from the binary package to some directory
2. create a specfile describing your package (meta information) and potential pre/post (un)installation scripts.
3. use rpmbuild to create rpm from that direcotry as defined in specfile

Comment: And how do I know where those files go to? Not mentioning the data which are only used to alter target files.

Comment: @macias: for simple self extracting archives installers you will know... for more complicated, you have to compare system snapshot before and after installation. I have seen nice tutorial some time ago. Will try to find it.

Comment: I would be grateful, because I have in mind something more than just unzip/unrar ;-)